# How to decrease the density of x-ticks in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have some data, based on which I am trying to build a countplot in seaborn. So I do something like this:

```
data = np.hstack((np.random.normal(10, 5, 10000), np.random.normal(30, 8, 10000))).astype(int)
plot_ = sns.countplot(data)
```

and get my countplot:

[image]

The problem is that ticks on the x-axis are too dense (which makes them useless). I tried to decrease the density with `plot_.xticks=np.arange(0, 40, 10)` but it didn't help.

Also is there a way to make the plot in one color?

Comment: Don't use `countplot` for this application. Use, e.g. `distplot`, or just `plt.hist`.

Comment: You can increase the `figsize` of the plots to fill the entire window. Then, you get the `xticks` not being cluttered. Inorder to keep the same colors throughout the `countplot`, you can do `sns.countplot(data, color='r', saturation=1)`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### Tick frequency

There seem to be multiple issues here:

- 1. You are using the = operator while using plt.xticks. You should use a function call instead (but not here; read point 2 first)!
- 2. seaborn's countplot returns an axes-object, not a figure

     - you need to use the axes-level approach of changing x-ticks (which is not `plt.xticks()`)

Try this:

```
for ind, label in enumerate(plot_.get_xticklabels()):
    if ind % 10 == 0:  # every 10th label is kept
        label.set_visible(True)
    else:
        label.set_visible(False)
```

#### Colors

I think the data-setup is not optimal here for this type of plot. Seaborn will interpret each unique value as new category and introduce a new color. If i'm right, the number of colors / and x-ticks equals the number of np.unique(data).

Compare your data to seaborn's examples (which are all based on data which can be imported to check).

I also think working with seaborn is much easier using pandas dataframes (and not numpy arrays; i often prepare my data in a wrong way and subset-selection needs preprocessing; dataframes offer more). I think most of seaborn's examples use this data-input.

Comment: How do you do this for jointplot's ```'JointGrid' object has no attribute 'get_xticklabels'```

Answer (score 12):

even though this has been answered a while ago, adding another perhaps simpler alternative that is more flexible.

you can use an [matplotlib axis tick locator](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html) to control which ticks will be shown.

in this example you can use `LinearLocator` to achieve the same thing:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

data  = np.hstack((np.random.normal(10, 5, 10000), np.random.normal(30, 8, 10000))).astype(int)
plot_ = sns.countplot(data)
plot_.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.LinearLocator(10))
```

Answer (score 8):

Since you have tagged `matplotlib`, one solution different from setting the ticks visible `True/False` is to plot every `n`th label as following

```
fig = plt.figure(); np.random.seed(123)

data = np.hstack((np.random.normal(10, 5, 10000), np.random.normal(30, 8, 10000))).astype(int)
plot_ = sns.countplot(data)

fig.canvas.draw()
new_ticks = [i.get_text() for i in plot_.get_xticklabels()]
plt.xticks(range(0, len(new_ticks), 10), new_ticks[::10])
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

As a slight modification of the accepted answer, we typically select labels based on their value (and not index), e.g. to display only values which are divisible by 10, this would work:

```
for label in plot_.get_xticklabels():
    if np.int(label.get_text()) % 10 == 0:  
        label.set_visible(True)
    else:
        label.set_visible(False)
```