# Adjusting date tick settings on seaborn lineplot

Tags: python, seaborn, axis, line-plot

I'm experiencing crowding on my x-axis when using lineplot in seaborn.

I initially plotted the data with the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import seaborn as sns

for state in states_list:
    starting_point = state_covid_data[(state_covid_data.cases > 9) & (state_covid_data.state == state)]
    plot = sns.lineplot(data=starting_point, x='date', y='cases')
plot
```

Here is the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeh34.png

To try and fix the crowding, I adjusted my code as follows from the recommendation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947115/how-to-decrease-the-density-of-x-ticks-in-seaborn) answer:

```
for state in states_list:
    starting_point = state_covid_data[(state_covid_data.cases > 9) & (state_covid_data.state == state)]
    plot = sns.lineplot(data=starting_point, x='date', y='cases')
    for ind, label in enumerate(plot.get_xticklabels()):
        if ind % 10 == 0:  # every 10th label is kept
            label.set_visible(True)
        else:
            label.set_visible(False)
    plot
```

This resulted in only one date showing up on my x-axis: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Md8x1.png

Any recommendations how to to fix this? Ideally I would like to select which ticks appear. Even better would to be able to substitute certain ticks for my own values.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Try changing the 10 to 2. That will show every second label. In general, try playing around with that value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, other than 1, every other value ends up with the same chart as the below showing only the first date.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Md8x1.png